Equivalent impedance seen into drain
I can't understand or simplify the Zx in the picture

is equal to that of



Ignoring M1 can you see that there must be an impedance created by CGD and CGS?
That's basically the \$\dfrac{1}{sC_{eq}}\$ bit i.e. the reactance of both capacitors in series.
Then can you see that this capacitance is in parallel with another impedance due to M1 and the feedback effect of the two capacitors above?
Can you take it from here?
